# Regular Expression to ignore empty href

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have written one function to replace value of `href` with somevalue + original `href` value

say:-

```
<a href="/somepage.htm" id="test">
```

replace with

```
<a href="http//www.stackoverflow.com/somepage.htm" id="test">
```

Places where no replacement needed:-

```
<a href="http//www.stackoverflow.com/somepage.htm" id="test">
 <a href="#" id="test">
<a href="javascript:alert('test');" id="test">
<a href="" id="test">
```

I have written following method, working with all the cases but not with blank value of `href`

```
public static string RelativeToAbsoluteURLS(string text, string absoluteUrl, string pattern = "src|href")
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return text;
        }
        String value = Regex.Replace(text, "<(.*?)(" + pattern + ")=\"(?!http|javascript|#)(.*?)\"(.*?)>", "<$1$2=\"" + absoluteUrl + "$3\"$4>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

        return value.Replace(absoluteUrl + "/", absoluteUrl);
    }
```

Written `?!http|javascript|#` to ignore `http, javascript, #`, so it is working for these cases, but if we consider following part

```
(?!http|javascript|#)(.*?)
```

And replace this `*` with `+`

```
(?!http|javascript|#)(.+?)
```

It is not working for empty case.

Comment: question is big enough, I need it to work with `<a href="" id="test">` case

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: obligatory reference: [You can't parse HTML with RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1159478)

Comment: thanks for your comment, I have written a separate class for HTML parsing, and this method is part of utility class, which has certain methods for certain special scenario and this function is one of them.

Comment: here I am not expecting that this method should work with tags, the only expectation is it should work with `""` And also I am not expecting that it should work for all the cases[as regular expression is not the best way], at least for those I want

Comment: I tried `(?!http|javascript|#)(.*?){2,}` also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `*` to `+` does not work, because you got it completely wrong:

- `*` means "zero or more"
- `+` means "one or more"

So with `+` you are forcing the content to **be** at the place, rather that allowing the content to be missing.

Another thing you got wrong is the placement. The `*` at that place refers to `.`. Together, they mean "zero or more characters". So, this part **already does not require** any content. Therefore, since your regex currently does not work with null-content, something **other** seems to be requiring that.

Looking at the preceding expressions:

```
(?!http|javascript|#)(.*?)
```

The `?!` is a zero-width negative lookahead. Zero-width. Negative. That means that it will not require any content either.

So, I got your code, pasted it into [the online compiler](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php), then I fed it with your example `<a href="" id="test">`:

using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "<a href=\"\" id=\"test\">";
        string pattern = "src|href";
        string absoluteUrl = "YADA";
        string value = Regex.Replace(text, "<(.*?)(" + pattern + ")=\"(?!http|javascript|#)(.*?)\"(.*?)>", "<$1$2=\"" + absoluteUrl + "$3\"$4>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

and guess what it works:

```
Compiling the source code....
$mcs main.cs -out:demo.exe 2>&1

Executing the program....
$mono demo.exe 
<a href="YADA" id="test">
```

So, either you are not telling the truth, or you have changed the code when posting it here, or you've got something completely other messed up in your code, sorry.

EDIT:

So, it turned out that the href="" was meant to be ignored.

Then the simplest thing you can do it to add another negative-lookahead that will block the `href=""` case explicitely. However, note that the placement of that group will be different. The current group is inside the quotes from href, so it cannot "peek" how the whole href-quotes look like. The new group must be before the quotes.

```
"<(.*?)(" + pattern + ")=(?!\"\")\"(?!http|javascript|#)(.*?)\"(.*?)>"
```

Note that just-before the first quote from href, I've added a `(?!\"\")` that will ensure that "there will be no such case that quote follows a quote".

Comment: you explained it well, but I don't want to replace it to YADA, it should be as it is, as it is for `javascript` and `#`, so it should not replace with YADA

Comment: @vikas: wait, so you want the `href=""` to be **not** hit by the parser?

Comment: but other cases are getting lost, it is losing original value

Answer (score 0):

I know that you are asking for RegEx.

But here is an alternative, because I think the use of `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` worths it.
This way you also you can reuse the helpers functions:

```
public string RelativeToAbsoluteURLS(string text, string absoluteUrl, string pattern = "src|href")
{
    if (isHrefRelativeURIPath(text)){
        text = absoluteUrl + "/" + System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("///days/hours.htm", @"^\/+", "");
    }

    return text;
}

public bool isHrefRelativeURIPath(string value) {
    if (isLink(value) ||
        value.StartsWith("#") ||
        value.StartsWith("javascript"))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Others Custom exclusions

    return true;
}


public bool isLink(string value) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return false;

    return Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("http://" + value, UriKind.Absolute);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andre, but this will work only for those cases having only uri not string with html stuff like href="http://someexample.com" :(